# Sublime 3 install, "breaks existing package"

Tags: linux-mint, sublime-text-3

Attempting to install using the debian package under Mint produces the following error. I also have sublime 2 installed.

[image]

Comment: Can you ignore the error and install it? Or does it not let you

Comment: Nope, doesn't let me :(

Comment: where did you get the "Debian package"? Have you also tried installing Sublime from some other source previously? How did you install Sublime Text 2?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes, I think I just had to do a manual install

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just happened to me, did it manual:

```
sudo dpkg -r sublime-text-installer
sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-3065_amd64.deb # <- of course, depends on your version
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Just before installing the new package run this:

```
sudo apt-get purge sublime-text-installer
```